# Run Zend Framework 2 inside folder

Tags: php, localhost, zend-framework2

I have a requirement for running Zend Framework 2 project on server IP address for temporary. I have to run two Zend Framework 2 projects as http:// IP-ADDRESS/project1 AND http:// IP-ADDRESS/project2. I searched out but getting examples with virtual host. Did anybody know how to do that OR some tutorial url for doing that.

I tried without virtual on direct running the path http:// localhost/project1/public but It gave me error like 'Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.'. While same structure working fine with virtal host.

Comment: The error you've got means that the path to zf2 isn't set correctly. That's where you need to look to resolve this.

Comment: Yes, today I tried on with putenv() for zend lib path. Now it working. However on my actual project, I got problem using ZfcUser plugin redirection where i got 404, But If  i disable session check, It look code is working.

Comment: I got problem for ZfcUser, We have some custom code for redirection which did the virtual-host specific check. So Now ZF2 working fine under localhost subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Env variable using putenv solve the problem, So question must be answered.